Help calculating and simulating buck converter
I want to simulate a DCDC buck converter to go from 6V to 3.3V, with a max. output current of 100mA.
I'm using this buck converter online calculator to find out the values I need. This is the results I obtain:

It doesn't mention the capacitor I need, but it does calculate the required inductor and duty cycle.
I have plugged these values into a CircuitLab buck converter example, but I don't obtain the desired output:



You can simulate the circuit here.
What do I need to do to achieve an output of 100mA @ 3.3V? (I'm not concerned about the ripple at this point)

You show a PMOS, and a common-ground signal source. What is Vgs(on) and Vgs(off) intended to be, and is that consistent with the simulation?

I'm not sure what the original simulation got wrong since I didn't check it - that's on you. But this one works as you expect:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The input current envelope:

The input and inductor currents in steady-state:

Things to keep in mind:

Run the simulation for a number of complete PWM cycles. Set "Stop Time" to, say, 500 PWM cycles. That is 500/20k. One PWM cycle lasts, by definition, 1/20kHz = 50μs. Writing 500/20k is clearer IMHO than writing 500*50E-6. CircuitLab allows expressions most everywhere.

Have an integer number of time steps within each PWM cycle. In this case we set 100 steps/cycle, that is 1/100/20k.

Set "Skip Initial" to Yes, since the steady state solution for this circuit is useless.


When using PWSREPEAT here, the output voltage can be just 0/1V since VCVS1 then steps that voltage up times VCC. The PWM duty cycle and frequency can be entered easily like this:


0,1 means "1V at t=0"
0.6/20k,0 means "0V at \$t=0.6\times{\rm period}\$"
1/20k,0 means "keep 0V till end of the period, the period length \$T=(1/(20\cdot10^3)){\rm\ s}\$"
the PWS[REPEAT] source keeps the voltage constant until the next line in the CVS field. So, it outputs 1V from t=0 to t=30μs, then 0V until t=50μs and loops back to t=0.


It takes a long time for the output voltage to stabilize after power-up. That is normal. You need to be patient and wait :)

Use real components - most simulators have less trouble with them. A simulator that uses ideal components - say ideal diodes - is much harder to make. This means:

the diode must be non-ideal,
the inductor must have some series resistance,
the capacitor must have some series resistance,
the switching transistor should resemble a real part.


Connect the voltage source that controls the gate between Gate and Source of the mosfet. V(GS) is what controls the mosfet, not V(G0).




What do I need to do to achieve an output of 100mA @ 3.3V?


Ensure that the P channel MOSFET is ideal i.e. doesn't drop any volts between drain and source when activated
Ensure that the P channel MOSFET is ideal in that when deactivated it is fully open circuit
Ensure that the MOSFET is full activated and deactivated by the control signal
Ensure that the diode is ideal (zero volt drop when conducting and full open-circuit when not conducting)

Alternatively use a slightly higher value of duty cycle to accommodate those losses and hopefully, you should see a constant 3.3 volt output. Better still use a feedback loop that controls the duty cycle based on the output hitting the required level of 3.3 volts.
